# Pyinstaller gets stuck on Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc

Tags: pyinstaller

I am currently having an issue with the python module pyinstaller. When I try to build something, it gets stuck on Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc

What gets displayed in terminal:

[image: What gets displayed in terminal]

When I check the system monitor, I get this:

[image: Result when checking system monitor]

I don't think it should be taking this long, as the application is just a simple gtk program. Answers would be appreciated!

Comment: I know this is old, but I am having this issue or a related one too. As R-oughcode says, it happens when I build it on a remote drive on my corporate network, that line is very slow. As it happens, it doesn't terminally hang for me but that step takes an extremely long time. When I run PyInstaller locally, it's fine. I'm not especially looking for a fix, just adding a comment for anyone else who comes across this.

Answer (score 2):

It gets hung there if I build it off my a virtual drive. When I built it off my C: drive on my laptop it compiled fine. I assume that it needs something from my operating system.

I compiled it with: pyinstaller.exe --onedir --windowed --icon=espresso.ico master_project_data.py